# Flash AS3:Constructor functions must be instance method

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

Hello guys i have a problem and no idea how to fix it :( Can someone tell me how to do it?

Constructor functions must be instance methods.

So here is my code:

```
package
{
    import com.coreyoneil.collision.CollisionList;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;    

    public class terrain extends Sprite
    {
        private var wheel:Ball;
        private var collisionList:CollisionList;
        private var speed:Number;

        private const GRAVITY:Number = .75;
        private const FRICTION:Number = .98;
        private const IMMOVABLE:Number = 10000;


        public function terrain():void
        {
            if(stage == null)
            {
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init, false, 0, true);
                addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, clean, false, 0, true);
            }
            else
            {
                init();
            }
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            collisionList = new CollisionList(terrain);

            wheel = new wheel(10);
            wheel.mass = IMMOVABLE * 2;
            addChild(wheel);
            collisionList.addItem(wheel);
            wheel.x = 30;
            wheel.y = 10;

            speed = 0;

            terrain.graphics.lineStyle(15);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateScene);
        }


        private function updateScene(e:Event):void
        {           
            var collisions:Array = collisionList.checkCollisions();

            if(collisions.length)
            {
                var collision:Object = collisions[0];
                var angle:Number = collision.angle;
                var overlap:int = collision.overlapping.length;

                var sin:Number = Math.sin(angle);
                var cos:Number = Math.cos(angle);

                var vx0:Number = wheel.vx * cos + wheel.vy * sin;
                var vy0:Number = wheel.vy * cos - wheel.vx * sin;

                // Unlike the other examples, here I'm choosing to calculate the amount
                // of bounce based on the objects' masses, with a default mass of 10000 (IMMOVABLE)
                // being used for the drawing the wheel is colliding with.  As such, the only
                // real variable in play here is the current vector of the wheel.
                vx0 = ((wheel.mass - IMMOVABLE) * vx0) / (wheel.mass + IMMOVABLE);
                wheel.vx = vx0 * cos - vy0 * sin;
                wheel.vy = vy0 * cos + vx0 * sin;

                wheel.vx -= cos * overlap /wheel.radius;
                wheel.vy -= sin * overlap / wheel.radius;

                wheel.vx += speed;
            }
            trace("down");
            wheel.vy += GRAVITY;
            wheel.vy *= FRICTION;
            wheel.vx *= FRICTION;

            wheel.x += wheel.vx;
            wheel.y += wheel.vy;

            if(wheel.x > stage.stageWidth) wheel.x = stage.stageWidth;  
            if(wheel.x < 0) wheel.x = 0;                                    
            if(wheel.y > stage.stageHeight - (wheel.height >> 1)) 
            {
                wheel.y = 10;   
                wheel.x = 30;
                wheel.vx = wheel.vy = 0;
            }

        }

        private function clean(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateScene);
        }




    }
    }
```

There are some comment in the code.. Just ignore it i have used example.

Comment: What is your question? What are you having problems with?

Comment: Its not necessary to make the `if (stage == null)` check in the constructor, because at this time a new object will be created that cannot be added to the stage before its construction has been finished. Thus the stage property will be always null in the constructor. Simply adding the listeners would be enough. The else-part will never be evaluated anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
collisionList = new CollisionList(terrain);
terrain.graphics.lineStyle(15);
```

This is error 1026, also thrown if the constructor is static, private or in your case used as an identifier. Either use this.graphics instead of terrain.graphics or just graphics.etc (remove terrain) and also pass 'this' as parameter for 'CollisionList'.

(Unrelated: Also it's better to name classes starting with a capital "Terrain")

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but if i use this i still get the same error in line 3 (where i start importing things)

Comment: Oh yeah there's another one:  "collisionList = new CollisionList(terrain);", also change it to new CollisionList(this). Basically you only need to use a class name as identifier if it have a static property or method and from another class, otherwise its 'this' or nothing from within the class.